# Google Maps Sample Code: Trying to figure out why I keep getting Auth Failure

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to test out the Google Maps sample code from the SDK, following the [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) from their website.

After a bit of tinkering with settings, build paths and class paths, I've managed to get it to compile and deployed onto my device (physical device, not emulator). However, I get an Authorization Failed error in the logcat. And I have entered my API Key into the AndroidManifest.xml.

Apart from that change, none of the other code in the example has been changed.

I know I have added the support jar and referenced the library project correctly, since the application compiles. All I can think of is that somehow the signing certificate is wrong. During the packaging, I see this:

```
[2013-01-28 10:35:00 - MainActivity] Using default debug key to sign package
[2013-01-28 10:35:00 - MainActivity] Using keystore: /home/user/.android/debug.keystore
[2013-01-28 10:35:00 - MainActivity] Packaging MainActivity.apk
```

So it's using the debug.keystore.

Using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android | grep SHA1
```

I find my debug certificate is:

```
SHA1: {KEY_HIDDEN}
```

So I add this onto the Google APIs console like so:

```
{KEY_HIDDEN};com.example.mapdemo
```

Since the sample app's package is *com.example.mapdemo*

And I get an API key. In my case, it's

```
AIzaSyAW8nihGO9uSW170YETE-Q1pPjFAW-B4M8
```

So I add it to my AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/demo_title"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here. -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyAW8nihGO9uSW170YETE-Q1pPjFAW-B4M8"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But yet, I keep getting:

01-28 10:54:39.423: E/Google Maps Android API(28778): Authorization failure.

And I don't know why... Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For device - you will have to create a signed application package.
 Also when you are generating the  debug certificate you have to use the keystore that you have created for the signing the application(Not the debug key store ).
 Update your key in manifest and try to run.
Hope this helps. 
 
 Edit:
    keytool -v -list -keystore **your_keystore**

Comment: the apk is automatically signed by Eclipse as it packages it. By default, it uses the generic debug keystore (~/.android/debug.keystore). I'm not packaging for release, so I have no release keystore yet.

The manifest has already been updated prior to me posting this question.

Comment: You can try changing the keystore. Window--> Preferences-->Android-->Build--> Custom debug store.

Comment: The keystore is correctly pointing to the debug keystore. I also verified the apk generated by eclipse, extracted the certificate and checked the signature against the keystore certificate. They match, so the signing is correct. And the signature also matches against what I have entered on the API page. I have even tried a fresh project, not the sample one, so see if there was something within the sample code causing a problem. Same issue.

Comment: @ Blender : Can you please check what service is enabled in your google api console? It should be **Google Maps Android API v2**.

Comment: I had the **Google Maps API v2** on my console, not the **Google Maps _Android_ API v2**. Changing that and regenerating the key and adding that to my code has fixed the auth error on my "from scratch project", but the sample code is still not working. I regenerated it and now I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity` in my logcat.

Comment: If this has solved the issue -E/Google Maps Android API(28778): Authorization failure. Please mark it as the Answer. Also java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity please ask a different question here on SO.